# Prevent iframe from auto reloading when new iframe is added to parent

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a function of code that loads a card with an iframe when a button is clicked. Here's a small snippet of it:

```
document.getElementById("apps").innerHTML += `
          <div id="${appname}" class="app" style="display:block;">
          <div id="${appname}header" class="card ${object[appname].color}" style="width: ${object[appname].cardw}; height: ${object[appname].cardh};">
            <div class="card-content white-text">
              <span class="card-title center black-text">${object[appname].name}</span>
              <iframe id="${object[appname].repo}frame" src="custom/${object[appname].repo}/index.html" scrolling="no" style="width: ${object[appname].framew}; height: ${object[appname].frameh}; transform: scale(${object[appname].scale}); 
              transform-origin: 0 0;"></iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
          `;
```

The problem is, `apps` contains multiple iframes, and when i add a new one all the other ones reload. This is a very big deal, as i am using a text editor and i dont want it to reload. I'd prefer a simple solution, but i can be hacky too. How would I stop the iframe from reloaded when another iframe is added to the parent?

Comment: well you can not use `+= innerHTML` , you got to append the element

Comment: How would I do that

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append

Comment: Cool, how would i turn my current text into an element though?